# jQuery Deferred set default state

Tags: jquery, ajax

Consider a function that may or may not execute an AJAX request. `$.ajax` returns a [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instance. For chainability, the function should always return a [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) instance.

```
function doAjaxReq() {
    if (conditional_is_true) {
         return (
              $.ajax(
               ....
              );
         );
    } else {
        // Create a Deferred instance
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        // Set the Deferred state to "done"
        // ????
        return deferred;
    }
}
```

Imagine a few other similar functions like `doAjaxReq2`, `doAjaxReq3`, etc. They will be chained as follows:

```
doAjaxReq()
    .done(function() {
        doAjaxReq2()
            .done(function() {
                ....
            })
        .fail(ajaxFailHandler)
    })
    .fail(ajaxFailHandler);
```

How can the default state of a new [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object be set? In this case be set to a resolved state so the `done()` callbacks are triggered immediately even if an AJAX request is never attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $.Deferred().resolve();
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/

Comment: Nice! I should have caught that one.